# Error: "too many initializers for 'const int [4]'"

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, initializer-list

This error came up after verifying the Arduino code. I appreciate any help I can get! :)

```
const int NUM_OF_KEYS = 4;

const int THRESHOLD = 5;

const int NOTE_LENGTH = 50;

const int VEL_SENSE_VAL = 2;

const int midiChan = 1;

const int midiNote[NUM_OF_KEYS] = {86, 84, 83, 81, 79, 77, 76, 74, 72, 71, 69, 67, 65, 64, 62, 60};

const int triggerSensor[NUM_OF_KEYS] = {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10, A11, A12, A13, A14, A15};
```

Comment: Your `NUM_OF_KEYS` is only `4`, but you initialize `midiNote` and `triggerSensor` arrays with 16 variables. Of course you get a error, and compiler told you about it.

Answer (score 3):

You've declared `NUM_OF_KEYS = 4;` and then told the compiler to make an array of size `NUM_OF_KEYS` (4), and to put `16` elements in it. Seems like you should just update to `NUM_OF_KEYS = 16;` in your first line.

Side note, it might behoove you to learn a bit more about basic c++ fundamentals and syntax before jumping into arduino programming.